# How to require user open camera permission when lunch the apps

Tags: android-studio

I already add the camera permission in AndroidManifest.xml, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`. I want to do when user download the apk, the user open the apps first time it will pop up camera permission to require user allow. Can I know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.android.permission.CAMERA},
                    1);
```

Add this in your main activity's onCreate method

Comment: thank you for your reply, it works, but need to change to ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);